# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY seems to increment the auto_increment column when triggered

Tags: mysql

Consider the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE USER1
(
  pkUSER1_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  DATE_UPDATED TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (pkUSER1_ID),
  CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (NAME)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO USER1
   SET NAME = 'asdf'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE DATE_UPDATED = NOW();

INSERT INTO USER1
   SET NAME = 'asdf'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE DATE_UPDATED = NOW();

INSERT INTO USER1
   SET NAME = 'asdf1'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE DATE_UPDATED = NOW();

SELECT * FROM USER1;
```

And now notice the result set.  The auto_increment was increased despite nothing being inserted.

```
+------------+---------------------+-------+
| pkUSER1_ID | DATE_UPDATED        | NAME  |
+------------+---------------------+-------+
|          1 | 2010-02-09 13:29:15 | asdf  |
|          3 |                NULL | asdf1 |
+------------+---------------------+-------+
```

I get different behavior on two separate servers... the output above is from MySQL v5.0.45 running on 2.6.9-023stab048.6-enterprise (I think it's Red Hat).  The problem doesn't exist on MySQL v5.0.51a-24+lenny2-log running on 2.6.26-2-amd64 (which is obviously Debian).

Is there a configuration setting I can change to avoid this?  I have around 300 users in my database, but due frequency that the insert/update statement is run, the latest user id is over 600,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug... http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28781

Not sure why the client is running a 3 year old version of MySQL.

Comment: From that ticket: *«I am closing this down as 'not a bug'. The behaviour of auto_increment can be controlled through the config parameter (as mentioned earlier) and the gaps in the autoinc values are expected.

I'll make sure that we add more to the documentation to clarify this point.»*